# releasePublishArtifactsAction doesnt seem to catch

Tags: scala, sbt, sonatype, sbt-release, sbt-sonatype

I am trying to publish a multi project to sonatype using sbt-release, sbt-pgp and sbt-sonatype plugins.

while running: `sbt publishLocalSigned` I see the `.asc` file published.
but when running sbt release to sonatype I can only see the `.md5` and `sha1` files.

here is my `release.sbt`:

```scala
    import ReleaseTransformations._


    // publishing
    publishMavenStyle in ThisBuild := true

    credentials in ThisBuild += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials_sonatype")

    publishTo in ThisBuild := {
      val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
      if (version.value.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
        Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
      else
        Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
    }

    publishArtifact in Test := false

    pomIncludeRepository in ThisBuild := { _ => false }

    pomExtra in ThisBuild := {
        <url>my.url</url>
        <licenses>
          <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
          </license>
        </licenses>
        <scm>
          <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:url.git</connection>
          <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:url.git</developerConnection>
          <url>url</url>
        </scm>
        <developers>
          <developer>
            <id>dev</id>
            <name>dev</name>
            <email>dev@gmail.com</email>
          </developer>
        </developers>
    }

    // use maven style tag name
    releaseTagName in ThisBuild := s"${name.value}-${(version in ThisBuild).value}"

    // sign artifacts

    releasePublishArtifactsAction in ThisBuild := PgpKeys.publishSigned.value

    // don't push changes (so they can be verified first)
    releaseProcess in ThisBuild := Seq(
      checkSnapshotDependencies,
      inquireVersions,
      runTest,
      setReleaseVersion,
      commitReleaseVersion,
      tagRelease,
      publishArtifacts,
      setNextVersion,
      commitNextVersion,
      pushChanges,
      releaseStepCommand("sonatypeRelease")
    )
```

my `plugin.sbt`:

```
    addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")

    addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-coveralls" % "1.2.7")

    addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "2.3")

    addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.1.0")

    addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.11")
```

I am sure my gpg keys are properly set, otherwise I wont be able to run the `publishLocalSigned` but it seems like I miss something to my sbt-gpg plugin to kick in on release.

sbt version is 1.2.8 and I tried to downgrade to 0.13.17 and got the same behaviour.

I have to mention I was mainly following the jackson-module-scala approach:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/release.sbt